# Getting mouse coords from large control

Tags: c#

I have large PictureBox (10000, 10000) on docked panel (DockStyle.Fill) with AutoScroll = true on my form and some elements must be drawn on it in specific coords (place where i click). I got coords by MouseClick event:

```
_coords = PictureBox.PointToClient(e.Location);
```

But _coords always different if i scroll panel.

If my panel stay in not scrolled condition and i move cursor to panel right side it show me X = 1920, but if i scroll panel and move cursor on same place it show me X = 2500.

Can't paste images here to illustrate process.

Links to sample images:

[Image1](http://postimg.org/image/5job2f1gn/)

[Image2](http://postimg.org/image/9p5dmq399/)

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Did you try to get X and Y on MouseMove Event of Picturebox in global variables `_x = e.X; _y = e.Y`

Comment: `private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Text = String.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
        }`